# Find Maximum Subarray that adds to the Minimum Value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Given an array of non-negative integers, design the simplest possible algorithm to find  the largest sized subarray that adds up to the smallest value.**

My thought process has been that since they are non-negative integers, the array with smallest sum is always going to be a single cell array with only the minimum value from the original array. If I'm understanding it correctly, it depends on what takes higher priority, having a higher length or a smaller value. However, it's never made clear in the question which one takes priority.

Am I on the right track with this problem, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Zero is non negative

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the longest consecutive section made entirely of zeros, otherwise, if no zeros exist, the minimum value as a single element.